# Отдельные лог-файлы для приложения

Tags: linux, логирование, embedded

Есть приложение на с++, пишущее данные в лог. Изначально была идея с использованием системного syslogd писать сообщения в /var/log/messenges.
Приложение пришлось адаптировать под Embedded-систему c BusyBox. 
Отсюда собственно и вопрос, как сделать отдельный лог-файл (или даже не 1) для конкретного приложения? возможно ли это сделать, используя syslog.conf и если да то как примерно?

Comment: Вы бы посмотрели какой именно логгер у вас в системе. Их десяток разных наберется и у каждого свои конфиги.

Comment: Так же зависит от конкретного приложения, у многих приложений в их конфигах есть выбор средств логирования

Comment: я же, предлагая задать новый вопрос, написал, что именно стоит уточнить: какой версии и какой дистрибутив используется, какая программа выполняет функции системного логгера (syslog).

Comment: @ Mike. Приложение самописное. Поэтому и спрашиваю как его логгировать. Каким образом можно посмотреть какой логгер используется?

Comment: @alexander barakin дистрибудив собран с помощью Yocto Project и предоставлен мне. Каким образом можно посмотреть какой логгер используется?

Comment: @Sebefour, `$ ps | grep log` (или `$ ps aux | grep log`) — покажет имена процессов, содержащих строку `log`.

Comment: а в чем сложность принести syslog с собой?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сделать перенаправление вывода процесса в файл:

```
foo > allout.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Ещё вариант `foo &> text.log`